# Incompatibility of Material UI Grid in IE 11

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to achieve the following grid layout using the Grid component in Material UI.

[image]

I was able to achieve this layout in Chrome and Firefox using the following sample code, however in IE 11 all the grid items overlap and the textfields get expanded.

```js
<Grid container direction='column' spacing={0}> // Grid 1 (Level0)

  <Grid item xs={12}> // Grid 1 (Level1)
   <Grid container direction='row' spacing={0}>
     <Grid item xs={6}>
       Logo
     </Grid>
     <Grid item xs={6}>
       FormControl
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
  </Grid>

  <Grid item xs={12}> // Grid 2 (Level1)
    <Grid container direction='column' spacing={0}>

     <Grid item xs={12}> // Grid 1 (Level2)
      <Grid container direction='row' spacing={0}>
       <Grid item xs={12}>
         <TextField/>
       </Grid>
       <Grid item xs={12}>
        <TextField/>
       </Grid>
      </Grid>
     </Grid>

     <Grid item xs={12}> // Grid 2 (Level2)
      <Grid container direction='row' spacing={0}>
       <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField />
       </Grid>
       <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField />
       </Grid>
      </Grid>
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
 </Grid>

 <Grid item xs={12}> // Grid 3 (Level1)
  <Grid container direction='row' spacing={0}>
   <Grid item xs={6}>
    Label
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={6}>
    Label
   </Grid>
  </Grid>
 </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong!

Comment: Are you already using babel-polyfill ? https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: @JulienD  yes, I have installed it and included(imported) in index.js.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/), Material UI supports IE 11.

However, the Grid formatting issues as you describe them are a [documented](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15443) problem with a fix. The issues are a result of a Grid item not having the flex size set. In Chrome you can just use `<Grid item>`, but for IE you need to explicitly set the flex size `<Grid item xs=12>`.

How does this relate to you?

In your case it looks like your child `<Grid container>` components should also be `<Grid item>` components. That is, they should be of the form `<Grid container item>`, but they should also have the flex size set `<Grid container item xs=12>`.

Below is a sample snippet:

```
<Grid container> 
  <Grid item xs={12}>
   <Grid container item xs={12}>
     <Grid item xs={6}>
       Logo
     </Grid>
     <Grid item xs={6}>
       FormControl
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```